# Are Cputime limit exceeded and Floating point exception stderrs?

Tags: macos, stderr

I am getting Runtime error - `Floating point exception: 8` and `Cputime limit exceeded: 24` as I wanted to two different problems. I am getting the error displayed on the terminal after executing the problem and I can't redirect it to a text file using `./a.out 2> err.txt` and not even to stdout. What type of errors are these. How can I redirect them to a text file or any file in general.

Answer (score 0):

`{ ./a.out; } 1>out.txt 2> err.txt` does the trick redirecting stdout to tmp.txt and stderr to err.txt.
The above mentioned errors in the question are not stderrs of the program you are executing, they are stderrs of the shell.